# Correct method to implement the oncomplete through a cursor

Tags: indexeddb

Good day, I am with certain difficulties to implement the oncomplete method with regard to the opening of the cursor. As the seat is asynchronous he makes the requisition and part to the next part of the code and is impossible to observe the return of the function outside the function. Would have a better way to do this ? Or how to resolve the problem of return ? As implements the oncomplete ? Below the code:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < tam; i++){
                var objectStorePresenca = db.transaction("tbl_PRESENCA").objectStore("tbl_PRESENCA");
                var indexPresenca = objectStorePresenca.index("COD_IDENT_REUNI");
                indexPresenca.openCursor(objetoReuniao[i].COD_IDENT_REUNI).onsuccess = function (event){
                    var vetor = event.target.result;
                    if (vetor) {
                        var obj = new Object();
                    obj.CODIGO_REUNIAO = vetor.value.COD_IDENT_REUNI;
                    obj.COD_IDENT_PESSO = vetor.value.COD_IDENT_PESSO;
                    obj.FLG_IDENT_PRESE = vetor.value.FLG_IDENT_PRESE;
                    ausentes.push(obj);    

                    vetor.continue();
                }/*else{
                    console.log(ausentes);
                    console.log(objetoReuniao);
                    // presentes.push(objetoReuniao);
                    // console.log(presentes);
                }*/
            }

        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell whether you're asking how to observe the "complete" event fired at a transaction, or how to write asynchronous code where you can't simply return a value.

**#1: How to observe the "complete" event.**

```
var tx = db.transaction("tbl_PRESENCA");
tx.oncomplete = function() {
  console.log("transaction is complete");
};
var objectStorePresenca = tx.objectStore("tbl_PRESENCA");
```

**#2: How to return a value from asynchronous code.**

```
function yourFunction(callback) {    
  var objectStorePresenca = ...; 
  var indexPresenca = ...;
  indexPresenca.openCursor(...).onsuccess = function (event){
    var vetor = event.target.result;
    if (vetor) {
      ...
      vetor.continue();
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  };
}

yourFunction(function() {
  console.log("cursor has hit end of range");
});
```